# Keys.ARROW_DOWN does not select an item in the 'Select Box'?

Tags: webdriver, selenium2, java

I have a select box which has 3 values in the drop-down. When I click on the select box and then further use `click()` on the value item , it works fine. but when I use `Keys.ARROW_DOWN` its displays the select values but does not click/select the item in drop down. Also I don't want to use 'Select' class for it.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl04_Pane2_AttributeDefinitionCategoryTest']/td[2]//td[2]")).click();

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl04_Pane2_AttributeDefinitionCategoryTest']/td[2]/div/select")).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
```

Also if the 'Id' of the select box changes dynamically, then should we use the webdriver 'Select' class for it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl04_Pane2_AttributeDefinitionCategoryTest']/td[2]/div/select")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

for an easy fix. However there are other ways to select by the value.

```
    Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl04_Pane2_AttributeDefinitionCategoryTest']/td[2]/div/select")));
    select.selectByVisibleText("Insert Text Here");
```

Comment: The `Select` class makes it very easy to use multi-option select boxes.  It has two useful methods, `selectByVisibleText(String)` and `selectByIndex(int)` which will let you respectively select by it's visible text and order in the list.  Here are the javadocs for this class http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html

Answer (score 0):

use `driver.switchto().activeelement()` before sending the arrow keys.