# Selenium: Incorrect drop down option selected

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, java

While passing a value, system selects a different value from the drop down in selenium web driver.

Following is the code written:-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Users_RadGrid_ctl00_ctl02_ctl03_RCNewJobType_Input']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Users_RadGrid_ctl00_ctl02_ctl03_RCNewJobType_Input']")).sendKeys(mystring[5]);

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Users_RadGrid_ctl00_ctl02_ctl03_RCNewJobType_Input']")).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN,Keys.ENTER);
```

Comment: You can use 'Select' class for selecting value from the drop down unless you don't want to use it. Select class is easier to use while working with drop-down

Comment: How is that related to Quality Center, if the code is for Selenium/Web Driver.

Comment: @Minion4:
I also tried to use "Select" but its giving following error
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "input"
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 02:56:46'

Code written for above is:
Select jobtype = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Users_RadGrid_ctl00_ctl02_ctl03_RCNewJobType_Input")));
jobtype.selectByVisibleText(mystring[5]);

Comment: I think you should use selectByValue.

Comment: I tried using it, but its not working. Is there any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

As Minion4 pointed out, you want to use '[select](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html)' and not 'sendKeys'. You can select by Value, ID, Index, or Visible Text.

Comment: I had the same thought. But in [this](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/9675/15319) question the user doesn't want to use Select. So was wondering if it could be a similar problem